# Can "go build" support armbe/arm64be

Tags: go

I need to Compile the go file to use in my Embedded device(aarch64be).

But "cmd/go: unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair linux/arm64be",

which means i cannot use this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can execute `go tool dist list` to the available supported platform. Check also [official doc](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GoArm)

Answer (score 1):

> which means i cannot use this?

Yes. "unsupported" means exactly this.